# Image registration, construction of Composite Image

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy

I'm working in an image registration algorithm. I have the **reference image(I1)** and the **sensed image(I2)**. The images are numpy arrays.

I implemented an fft algorithm that take **I1** and **I2** and returns a new image(**I3**) that is the result of aplying at I2 the transformations that would make possible the match between reference and sensed images.

Also this fft algorithm returns the transformations parameters that I used to transform **I2** in **I3**. More specifically also I3, the algorithm returns: scale factor, rotation angle and translation vector.

How I can generate a new composite image between **I1** and **I3**? Is there any function in any python library that makes this possible?

What I want to do is something like the image of the link(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv0ls.png) . Having the reference Image, sensed with the transformations to match with reference image,create the composite image between them (the picture of the bottom of the image). In my case I have only two images.

Comment: What do you mean by the "union"?  Also, are you sure that you have all your I1, I2, and I3 specified correctly in your problem statement?  (eg, why do you apply at I2, the transformation that would take I1 to I2?)

Comment: You are right, I make a mistake when write my problem. When I said union I want to reference at the alignment between images. I want to create the image as result of registration between reference and sensed image. I think that better way to say what I want to do is Image Compositing or Mosaicking between: reference image (I1) and  sensed image with transformations(I3).

Answer (score 0):

Use `skimage.transform.AffineTransform` to represent the transformations.  Apply them to the individual images using `skimage.transform.warp`.  While you can implement your own blending algorithms, I'd recommend Enblend (http://enblend.sf.net).  Here's a small demo for registering two images:

https://github.com/stefanv/scikit-image-demos/blob/master/register.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I've already calculated the translation vector (supouse that is [x,y]), and the angle of rotation (t). Then I transform the sensed image with this parameters and it's ready to overlap with reference image. How I can do that with scikit?

Comment: Here's a notebook showing how to create a panorama.  It covers your use-case too: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/scikit-image/scikit-image-demos/blob/master/pano/pano.ipynb